# Numerical value of an expression with a uniform step size

Tags: numerical-value

I have a complex expression that is so difficult to separate its Real part from it Imaginary part. What I thought of doing is to get the numerical value of the Real and Imaginary part, Then I will use that in plotting my graph. Now, how can I use Mathematica to get value for an expression,
let say from $ [0,8] $ with a step size of $ 0.1 $.
E.g: $u= \theta^2 + Erf[x + \gamma ]+ sqrt(\gamma + x^3) $ with the value of $ \theta $ given and $\gamma$ is a complex expression. I need the value of the real and imaginary part subject to a particular step size, without having to go manually. the step size will be in $  x $.
Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), it seems to me. You might also be interested in [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html). To get an idea of the tools, try evaluating `Table[ReIm[E^(-I x)], {x, 0, 5, 0.1}]`.

Comment: This "complex expression" is confusing. Could you clarify?

Comment: You need to give an example where all the quantities have explicit definitions, so people can work with your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Following @MarcoB comment closely,

```
g = I*y; (*g is for gamma*)

u = With[{t = 1}, t^2 + Erf[x + g] + Sqrt[g + x^3]]; (*t for theta*)

Table[{x, y, ReIm[u]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}] // 
  Flatten[#, 1] & // Grid
```